# adding icon to tabs in sencha touch 2

Tags: css, sencha-touch-2

I have set custom icon to tabs, but it takes the blue color of tab panel, how can i get the original color of the icons.

```
var tabPanel = Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel',{
tabBarPosition: 'bottom',                                                   
items:[
{   
title:'General',
iconCls:'icongen',
}
```

my css code

```
.icongen
{
   -webkit-mask-box-image: url("resources/images/general.png");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
.icongen
{
   background-image: url("resources/images/general.png");
}
```

use this :) this will solve your problem

Comment: I tried using this also but is does'nt work,actually i m trying to display it on the android amulator,but the blank image m getting.Is there any other solution?

Comment: But i don't think you should down vote coz its not working. Apart from that you sure you have this image in the project directory

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do, add the following to your css:

```
.x-tab .x-button-icon.icongen, .x-button .x-button-icon.x-icon-mask.icongen {
-webkit-mask-image: url(<PATH TO IMAGE>);
}
```

along with `iconCls` you might also have to use `iconMask: true`